# Delete DB by ContentProvider.delete() in android

Tags: android

I cannot delete DB.

```
Log.d("TAG4", "DB siza " + i);
```

Logcat:

> 2116-2116/com.james.test.wotclient D/TAG4﹕ DB size 601.

DB consist 601 elements. After that I want to delete all elements in DB when the programm finished;

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    int a = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Provider.URI_CONTENT, null, null);
    Log.d("end", "deleted " + a);
}
```

But logcat said:

> 2116-2116/com.james.test.wotclient D/end﹕ deleted 0

What I must done to delete fully DB? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that to get the number of rows in your database you are querying the database through the same contentprovider as you are using in your delete. There is not enough information to answer question. Are you using Sqlitebuilder, Is the database writeable. Need more code. What does your content provider look like